# Releasing versions while using Heroku with Github

Tags: heroku, github, release, versions

I am using Heroku to serve my static web application.  We've linked it with our github repository.

We are at a point in developing our application that we want to release it to our clients, however, we would like to continue developing it in the background.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how we can release a version to our clients, yet still be able to use our git repo to collaborate within the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your existing Heroku app as your development instance and spin up a new Heroku app for production. [Forking](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app#fork-application) your first app is probably the easiest way to do this, but I would recommend looking into Heroku [pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines):

> A pipeline is a group of Heroku apps that share the same codebase. Apps in a pipeline are grouped into "review", "development", "staging", and "production" stages

Don't be intimidated by everything on that page; basic pipeline use is actually quite simple:

- `git push` to your development instance, as usual
- When you're happy, promote code from one stage to the next

  - using Heroku's web interface, or
  - using `heroku pipelines:promote`

You don't have to have apps in every stage. For example, you can have a simple development-to-production pipeline. Pipeline promotions copy the compiled slug from one stage to the next, so they are very fast and you are guaranteed to get exactly the same code.

Comment: You can also set up GitHub deploys. We use Pipelines, but instead of promoting through the CLI, we rely on our Git branches. So when we push the `staging` branch up, it auto-deploys our Staging app. When we push to `master`, it auto-deploys our Production app.